# How to remove the selection frame around a layer

Tags: photo-editing

I'm trying to shrink a buddy's face using Photopea.  The Image of the 2nd layer still keeps its selection frame around the layer so I can't merge the 2 layers together.  Anyone know a way to get rid of this?  I just wanna merge the 2 layers and use the spot healing tool.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of "Photopea" -- but admittedly I may be out of touch.

In any event, in Photoshop you would **deselect** a selection in order to paint around it's edges. My **guess** would be to use the `Select` menu and "unselect" or "deselect".

Comment: It's not just an online cheapo generically photoshop-like app - it's an attempted low-rent direct knockoff - in the help section comments you can ***see*** the dev querying users who're asking for a given PS feature to be added to it to find out exactly where to put a given feature to keep it more like PS... sheesh. https://www.photopea.com/learn/creating-selections

Comment: Yeah, *clearly* it's a knock off.. I imagine Adobe will let it get to a certain point then **BAM** drop the hammer.

Comment: Wow, alright... I definitely thought that was a typo or like autocorrect mistake. I remember looking at the screenshot yesterday and I didn't realize it wasn't Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that as @Scott has suggested, there is a menu item under Select for Deselect.

[image]